# How to cancel the whole tpl dataFlow on first exception?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow

Consider the following example:

```
        ActionBlock<TimeSpan> ab = new ActionBlock<TimeSpan>(async _ =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(_);
            throw new Exception();
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue });

        ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d));
        ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromDays(1d));

        await ab.Completion;
```

As expected, I see in the output window that an exception is being thrown after 10s, but this does not cause completion of the dataFlow (a breakpoint after await ab.Completion will not get hit before 1 day).

In my case, I'd like to cancel the whole dataFlow in case there is an exception in one single computing step.

I cannot see how to do that using tpl dataflow...
Any suggestions?

Thanks...

[edit]As Ofir mentionned, I could do:

```
        ActionBlock<TimeSpan> ab = new ActionBlock<TimeSpan>(async _ =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Delay(_);
                throw new Exception();// Or any other Task thay may throw an exception.
            }
            catch(Exception)
            {
                cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
                throw;
            }
        }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {CancellationToken=cancelTokenSource.Token, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Int32.MaxValue });

        ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10d));
        ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromDays(1d));

        await ab.Completion;
```

But that's exactly what I'd like to avoid: typing the same try{}catch over and again... or worse: forgetting it... ;)

The next thing I could do is writing a replacement for ActionBlock's contructor to handle that (it would take an extra CancellationTokenSource parameter)...
I'm surprised this does not come directly with dataflow... Is it really the case?

[final edit]
It seems the answer is *there is no such thing in tpd dataFlow*, and a `ActionBlock "extension constructor" (in fact a static method)` accepting a CancellationTokenSource as parameter would be a possible workaround...

Comment: [`As with parallel loops and PLINQ queries, exceptions in such parallel processing do not forcibly interrupt other concurrent processing, nor is the construct’s processing considered completed the moment the exception occurs; if an exception does occur, the dataflow block will complete only once all processing has quiesced.`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/11/09/exception-handling-in-tpl-dataflow-networks/)

Comment: Thanks... I understand that every usage should be supported, but since _cancel everything upon first unexpected error_ is I guess a common scenario, I was wondering if I missed a dataFlow option... I'll write my `ActionBlock "extention constructor"` then... ;)

Answer (score 5):

The `Exception` you are throwing will put the `ActionBlock` into a faulted state
and will drop all buffered messages to drop and will not accept more messages.
This is true also with `CancelationToken` (that can be provided in the `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`)

Once the current processed messages will complete you will receive an `AggregateException` on the `await ab.Completion`.

As with `Task`, you have to take care of the abortion of the already executed message yourself.

For demonstration, in the example you've provided it can be achieved like this:

```
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var ab = new ActionBlock<TimeSpan>(async _  =>
{
    // await with cancellation token
    await Task.Delay(_, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions {CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = int.MaxValue});

ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
Thread.Sleep(15000);
cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
ab.Post(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100));

try { await ab.Completion; }
catch(TaskCancelationException ex)
{ }
```

In the above scenario, we are posting 2 messages that will run immediately.
After 10 seconds, the first message will cause the `Cancel` the `cancellationTokenSource` and causes the other message (That Delays for 20 seconds) to finish immediately, and puts the `ActionBlock` in cancelled state.
The next message that we try to post, is not accepted and will not be executed.

After 15 seconds we will get a `TaskCancelationException` while awaiting for `completion`.

Comment: Thank you.
That corresponds indeed to my understanding of tpl dataFlow, but I was hoping for a more integrated solution.
I want to react to an unhandled exception... Of course I could wrap all my actions into a `try{...}catch(){cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();throw;}`, but that is not really good to have to write it each time...
I was hoping tpl dataFlow would have a cleaner solution for that... But maybe there is none... ;)

Comment: @Sylvain you may implement easy wrapper for your `ActionBlock` with `try/catch` block in it, and use it across the application. This is kinda aspect-oriented approach.

Comment: Yes, that's the spirit... And it seems indeed that it is not included in the dataFlow component... I'll edit my question with the answer _there is no such thing_... Thanks again, Sylvain.